# The best practice for (unordered) map keys and values modification

Tags: c++, unordered-map

The map of the form `map<long long, vector<long long>>` is given. One has to take all keys and values modulo some integer `N`. Some keys can merge and corresponding values must join accordingly. For example, the map `{{1,{2,6,4}}, {5,{8,4,9}}, {10,{5,1,7}}}` should be equal to `{{1,{2,1,4}}, {0,{0,1,2,3,4}}}` after reduction modulo 5.

My way is in using a new map but I think there should be a better way.

code added

```
vector<long long> tmp;
//integer N, for example N = 5
int N = 5;
unordered_map<long long, vector<long long>> map;
//temporary map
unordered_map<long long, vector<long long>> map_tmp;
     for (auto & x : map)
        {
            tmp.clear();
            for (auto & y : x.second) tmp.push_back(y % N);
            ind = x.first % N;
            map_tmp[ind].insert(map_tmp[ind].end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
            sort(map_tmp[ind].begin(), map_tmp[ind].end());
            map_tmp[ind].erase(unique(map_tmp[ind].begin(), map_tmp[ind].end()), map_tmp[ind].end());
        }
        map = map_tmp;
```

Comment: Can you use C++17 or newer?

Comment: This seems like a heavy lift for `std::transform`. Anyway, if you have _working_ code and you're wondering how it could be improved, that's a question for [code review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions). But please do take a look at the how to ask, because in particular you will need to post _the code_ instead of an extremely brief high-level summary of the code.

Comment: what have you done? I see task description, but no attempts to solve it.

Comment: "should be equal" does that include the order of the vector elements?

Comment: keys in maps are `const`, at least you need to create new elements, and then I don't see the advantage over creating a new map

Comment: anyhow, when asking for a "better" way you should post a [mcve] of your current implementation and perhaps say what "better" you mean. It can be many different things, simplicity & readability, time / space efficiency, etc.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes

Comment: Existence of a (substantially) better way is rather improbable.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number nodes extracted from a map have mutable keys, so the elements could be re-used, however some will have to be discarded

Comment: @Caleth thats cool, didn't know that

Comment: `anc_tmp` vs `tmp` ? is this a typo? Looks like you are making some unnecessary copies, but your code is incomplete. You only need to add 2 or 3 lines to turn it into code others can understand

Comment: @Caleth, order does not matter.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, corrected. I use `tmp` for reduced vector in the current pair.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, "better" means  "time / space efficiency", especially time

Comment: with the 2-3 lines i was refering to declarations of variables that are currently missing. Please do read about [mcve]. I could guess what they are, but I might guess wrong and details do matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since apparently values in map are unique and after applying modulo operation values contains unique items, then you should use different data structure. for example:

```cpp
using Map = std::unordered_map<int, std::set<int>>;
```

`std::set` will handle uniqueness and order of items for given key.

Now the whole trick is to inspect API of `std::unordered_map` and `std::set` and how item can be inserted there. See:

- [std::unordered_map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert)
- [std::set::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert)

Note return value: `std::pair<iterator,bool>` which gives you iterator to inserted or exciting item in map/set.

Knowing this thing writing a code which is able to meet your requriements is quite simple:

```cpp
using Map = std::unordered_map<int, std::set<int>>;

Map moduloMap(const Map& in, int mod)
{
    Map out;
    for (const auto& [k, s] : in) {
        if (s.empty())
            continue;
        auto& destSet = out.insert({ k % mod, {} }).first->second;
        for (auto x : s) {
            destSet.insert(x % mod);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

[Live demo with tests](https://godbolt.org/z/dEYdanT3e)

Comment: but you should be able to approve answer. This is strange that SO has this limitation. If I remember correctly it wasn't like this when I started

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a `for` loop can be the easiest, clearest way to do something.

```
map<long long, vector<long long>> result;
for (const auto& [key, vec] : input) {
    process (result[key%5], vec);
    }
```

and `process` takes the `vector` by (non-const) reference and appends the reduced values from the second (const) argument.

---

## update

After seeing the code you posted, I have several suggestions:

1. use a `set` instead.  You are spending multiple steps to append the new values, sort the whole thing together, then remove duplicates.  Just use a `set` which maintains a single copy of each value automatically.
2. use structured binding in your loop.  Instead of `x.second` and `x.first` you can just name them `key` and `vec` as in my earlier post.
3. Assuming you still need `tmp`, declare it where you are calling `.clear()` now, instead of declaring it way up at the top of your code.  You don't need to clear it each time through the loop; it will be empty each time through the loop naturally.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number   As does my code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `input` is unchanged.  `result` is populated with the modulo keys and merged modulo values.  I don't _remove_ anything.

Comment: arghs, really sorry. Completely misread the code. I should take a break